# Nintendo 42 All-Time Classics online play

Tags: 42-all-time-classics

Dug this out for the first time in ages but can't seem to connect online with it. I entered my internet settings but its refusing to accept them. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I am correct in what game this is (a Nintendo DS title), it is because t[hey discontinued the online services for Nintendo DS back in 2014](https://www.nintendo.com/consumer/info/en_na/services-update.jsp):

> The Nintendo Wi-Fi Connection service, which provides certain online
>   functionality for many Wii, Nintendo DS, and Nintendo DSi software
>   titles, has been discontinued. This service change does not impact the
>   ability to play these titles offline. F
>
> Examples of Discontinued Functionality:
>   **Online play and matchmaking** Leaderboards and tournament data Sharing of user generated content (ghost data, user created levels)
>   User exchange of in-game items or characters (Global Trade Station)
>   Free add-on content or downloads (new levels, in-game items, Mystery
>   Gifts)
>
> Games and Systems Impacted:
>   **Wii, Nintendo DS and Nintendo DSi games that use the Nintendo Wi-Fi Connection service**, no longer have access to the features listed
>   above. This includes Wii mode on Wii U and Nintendo DS games played on
>   Nintendo 3DS family systems.

Comment: Ah thanks Ash, I had no idea. Shame though.

Answer (score 0):

Nintendo WFC shut down in May 2014. However, fans have created alternative servers to keep online functionality alive, the most popular option being [Wiimmfi](https://wiimmfi.de/). Club House Games (Asobi Taizen) is listed as [fully supported](https://wiimmfi.de/stat?m=25) by the Wiimmfi service. Since those are the US and Japanese names for 42 All-Time Classics, I expect that your version would work just fine.

A weakness in DS security has recently surfaced, allowing players to use these online servers just by changing the DNS in their DS connection profiles, no game modifications required. It should be a simple matter of manually specifying the DNS, but any error codes you may encounter can be checked [here](https://wiimmfi.de/error).

I would list the current DNS in my answer, but it is possible that it will change over time. A full tutorial from one of the fans behind this project, with an always up-to-date DNS address, exists here: